# Poor Profile Navigation at Area 51

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, area-51, navigation

There's a difference between "[The Discussion Zone](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com)" and the "[New Site Staging Zone](http://area51.stackexchange.com)" user profiles on Area 51, and no visible means to switch to "The Discussion Zone" from the "New Site Staging Zone". The problem: They maintain a very distinct and different type of profile with different information for each user, although reputation and badges are mirrored across them.

It would be nice if, at a bare minimum, both profiles were visible from either URI, as there are occasions when I asked a question and I want to review it, but I can't remember which of the proposals I asked it on. On my "Discussion Zone" profile I can see all my questions and answers, but on my "Staging Zone" profile I cannot.

Comment: +1 This is a hassle at the mo. Would love to view own discussion questions in fewer clicks from the main area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just added a "discussion user" link to the [Area 51 user page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/33577/md5sum), similar to the "main user" link on the [discussion user page](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/users/33577/md5sum).

This reduces the number of clicks to see your discussion questions and answers, but if it still seems unsatisfactory, we'll consider adding a "discussion" tab to the main user page, or something of the sort.

Comment: Wasn't there originally a discussion tab on the main user page? I think I remember there being a glimpse of one when Discussion first came out, but it was removed shortly afterwards.

Comment: @Grace Good memory. That tab contained a subset of the discussion user page, and that subset was an exact copy of the discussion user page's "stats" tab. It didn't feel very elegant, so we removed it. But if users want it back (or something like it), we're open to suggestions.